# I need to use \input to supply titles to \section, \subsection, and \subsubsection, but it only works for \section

Tags: input, latex2html

Here is a MWE.  Actually I am using latex2html for a web page.  LaTeX works using \protect, but not latex2html.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\section{\protect\input{titles/title-sample}}
\input{documents/document-sample}

\subsection{\protect\input{titles/subtitle-sample}}
\input{documents/document-sample}

\subsubsection{\protect\input{titles/subsubtitle-sample}}
\input{documents/document-sample}

\end{document}
```

OUTPUT:

1 <

<3>>Title Sample Sample text.

Comment: "LaTeX complains": what error or warning are you getting exactly? Is it "Argument of \@sect has an extra }." ? I get this when compiling your MWE. This is due to the argument of `\section` being  a moving argument and can be solved by protecting the command `\input`, like this: `\section{\protect\input{titles/title-sample}}`.

Comment: You are right.  \protect works with LaTeX.  But with latex2html, I receive a "? brace missing for \section" warning, and HTML output like:1 <
<3>>Title Sample Sample text.

Comment: You could define the titles as macros in the preamble. or even put all of them into one file.  In CPU years, IO takes forever.

Comment: Please give me a bit more detail.  Titles presently number about 150; maximum number is about 350.  The website is not going to be updated more than about once a day, so run time is not an issue.

Comment: I have no problem  using `htlatex` rather than `latex2html`. The usage of `catchfile` as proposed in the now deleted answer is better, as it avoids spurious spaces. Note that TeX4ht is actively maintained, which `latex2html` seems not to be.

Comment: I am using both TeX4th and latex2html.  And I will look again at the use of catchfile.